# Creating dynamic GIS charts in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, chart

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

I have generated a table which has road segments which get inundated during different flood events. I want to be able to add a pie chart to the map which shows that during each flood ARI (1y, 2y, 5y, 10y, 20y, 50y and 100y) x% of the road network in the AOI gets inundated.

I tried the following:

[image]

and get

[image]

The table looks like

[image]

Is it possible for me to add python code for the chart to add all the 1y lengths and display that number only, 2y total lengths etc only so that you get a pie chart with just the 7 categories. I need to automate this as it needs to be run in several areas and some of the input data changes.

Comment: I hope I understand your requirements correctly. You want _one_ chart for all roads? Use [Sumarize] (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000055000000) to calculate the sum of the length for the field ARI. Use the new table to create your chart.

Comment: _"The only worse design than a pie chart is several of them."_ Edward Tufte

Comment: Thanks Jen -I need the sum for the 7 ARI categories individually.

Comment: @radek, I love that quote.  I can't stand pie charts and the constant misuse of them.

Answer (score 3):

If you perform a [Dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000) command on your road data layer using the ARI field as the dissolve field it will create a new layer with one row for each unique value in the ARI field. You can the recalculate the length of each dissolved line and make the pie chart using the new layer.

Comment: Yes but the question was can it be done in the same dataset without having to create a new one. In excel you can use a function to sum a column where another column full fills a criteria -can the same be done in python?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) to select each field (1y, 2y etc) and sum them individually. Do not select a Case field. Unfortunately this will create a new output feature class.